# Django AJAX load-more-pagination with grouping

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, pagination

I have a page the displays messages grouped by date, and paginated via AJAX.
Consider the database contains 9 messages

- 3 was sent 9 Feb
- 3 was sent 8 Feb
- 3 was sent 7 Feb

and the Queryset is limited by 5 messages only.

View Code look like this

```
page = Paginator(queryset, int(request.GET['limit'])).page(request.GET['page'])
return paginator.page(request.GET['page']).object_list
```

HTML looks like this

```
<div class='messages-container'>
    {% include 'messages-snippet.html' %}
</div>
<a href='?page=2&limit=5'>Load older</a>
```

And the message-snippet's HTML looks like this

```
<div class='day-messages'>
    <span>9 Feb 2012</span>
    <p class='message'>Message 1</p>
    <p class='message'>Message 2</p>
    <p class='message'>Message 3</p>
</div>
<div class='day-messages'>
    <span>8 Feb 2012</span>
    <p class='message'>Message 4</p>
    <p class='message'>Message 5</p>
</div>
```

So when the Client click "load older", the browser will send the request to the same view, which will render this time on the message-snippet template, resulting in a HTML code like this

```
<div class='day-messages'>
    <span>8 Feb 2012</span>
    <p class='message'>Message 6</p>
</div>
<div class='day-messages'>
    <span>7 Feb 2012</span>
    <p class='message'>Message 7</p>
    <p class='message'>Message 8</p>
</div>
```

When I inject this html in the parent div, the result will be like this

```
<div class='messages-container'>
    <div class='day-messages'>
        <span>9 Feb 2012</span>
        <p class='message'>Message 1</p>
        <p class='message'>Message 2</p>
        <p class='message'>Message 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class='day-messages'>
        <span>8 Feb 2012</span>
        <p class='message'>Message 4</p>
        <p class='message'>Message 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class='day-messages'>
        <span>8 Feb 2012</span>
        <p class='message'>Message 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class='day-messages'>
        <span>7 Feb 2012</span>
        <p class='message'>Message 7</p>
        <p class='message'>Message 8</p>
    </div>
</div>
<a href='?page=2&limit=5'>Load older</a>
```

Now I have two groups for the same day (8 Feb 2012)
Currently I do a hackish solution to fix this. I detect if there is a repeated group, then merge them. Though, I don't like this solution. and I am wondering if someone thought of a better solution.

Note: I've seen [Django Endless Pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-endless-pagination/), it seems to handle the ajax part for me, but It doesn't solve the Grouping problem.
Also I thought of jQuery templates, but Still I have to hack to detect if the day-group is repeated or not.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you return HTML in AJAX responses than handling the repeated groups in jQuery seems the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you consider adjusting your view logic to limit based on the number of days, rather than the number of messages? This way you can offer a way to control the amount of data returned, but you won't have to rework your presentation layer to use client-side templating or do anything "hackish."

Alternatively, if this is not an option, the most straightforward and manageable approach seems to be handling all of your grouping on the client-side (e.g., JavaScript templating).

Comment: I think grouping on the client side is the best solution, although I'll keep my hackish solution for now.